# Usando Threads para atualizar GUI do windows

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma `thread` que quero que atualize um progress bar a cada iteração de uma `TQuery` por exemplo, porém o que eu notei é que para realizar o processo da query, tenho que colocar a função que faz select dentro da thread, como exemplo abaixo:

```
procedure TGeradorArquivos.GeraArquivo;
var
   CaminhoArquivo: String;
   Arquivo: TextFile;
begin
   Self.Query.Sql.Clear;
   Self.Query.Sql.Add('Select * from Teste');
   Self.Query.open;
   if Self.Query.Recordcount > 0 then
   begin
      AssignFile(Arquivo,CaminhoArquivo);
      Rewrite(Arquivo);
      FrmTeste.ProgressBar.Max := Self.Query.RecordCount;
      try
         while not Self.Query.Eof do
         begin
            Write(Arquivo,Self.Query.FieldByName('Campo').AsString);                       
            FrmTeste.ProgressBar.StebBy(1);
            Self.Query.Next;
         end;
      finally
         CloseFile(Arquivo);
      end;
   end;
end;
```

tem algum jeito de desvincular a função para atualizar a progress bar? Ou seja tirar o select dessa thread e deixar apenas para atualizar a GUI do formulário?

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso da seguinte forma:

```
while (Query.Eof = False) do
begin
  write(Arquivo,Query.FieldByName('Campo').AsString);                       
  FrmTeste.ProgressBar.StebBy(1);
  Application.ProcessMessages; {Atualiza tudo no Formulário}
  Query.Next;
end;
```

Se você executar esse bloco em Clique do Botão por exemplo, percorrera a Query e vai atualizar o progresso sem o uso da `thread`

Comment: `Application.ProcessMessages` não seria uma coisa ruim em uma iteração, ele vai processar qualquer mensagem pendente do windows

Comment: Se você precisa que a sua View sofra algum efeito visual com o retorno de um dado de um controler, voce vai ter que trabalhar com mensagens/notificações.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na omnithreadlibrary. Eles tem um jeito facil e pratico de implementar isso que voce precisa. https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary

Comment: @VictorTadashi Então, to fazendo isso no Delphi 7, acho que não da dai